# Checking for virus signature in a binary file bigger than the actual virus

Tags: c

I am trying to scan a binary file for a virus signature, but the file is bigger than virus. So I tried using a loop to start closer to EOF every loop.
I don't know whether I am using `fseek()` correctly. If I compare the virus signature to itself it works, but if to a file with the signature in it, it doesn't work.

Also, any help about how to go over a list of files in a folder would be appreciated.

```
//loop in main 
FILE * log = fopen("C:\\Users\\משתמש\\Desktop\\log.txt", "a");
    fprintf(log,"Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\n");
    fprintf(log,"folder to scan:\n");
    fprintf(log, "%s\n",argv[2]);
    fprintf(log,"virus signature:\n");
    fprintf(log, "%s\n",argv[3]);
    fprintf(log,"scanning option:\n");
    fprintf(log, "%s\n\n\n", argv[1]);
    fprintf(log, "results:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i+size <=size+1; i++)
    {
        found = 0;
        found = normalScan(file, virus, i, size, vsize);
        if (found == 1)
        {
            fprintf(log, "%s  infected!\n", argv[3]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found != 1)
    {
        fprintf(log, "%s  not infected\n", argv[3]);
        printf("%d", found);
    }
//function for scanning
int normalScan(FILE * file,FILE* virus, int start,int size,int vsize)
{
    int found = 0;
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char* virusSig = (char*)malloc((vsize + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (start + vsize <= size)
    {
        buffer[size] = 0;
        virusSig[vsize] = 0;
        fseek(file, vsize, start + 1);
        fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
        fseek(virus, vsize, start + 1);
        fread(virusSig, 1, vsize, virus);
        int result = strcmp(buffer, virusSig);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            printf("\nVirus was found in file\n");
            printf("%s\n\n%s\n\n", buffer, virusSig);
            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            found = -1;
        }
    }
    if (found != 0)
    {
       free(virusSig);
       free(buffer);
       return found;
    }
    else
    {
       free(virusSig);
       free(buffer);
       return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only ask one question. I recommend the first one. Then please explain more about "it doesn't work". What does it do? Crash? Hang? Wrong result? Make a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem. Ideally by leaving out any input reading, provide a hardcoded, preinitialised data structure to process.

Comment: The seek on the `virus` file shouldn't even be there. It should always read from start. You're looking for the entire sequence of bytes in that file to be present somewhere in the other file. You're also using the wrong function `strcmp` as opposed to `memcmp`. There is a *lot* in this code that frankly is either wrong or terribly inefficient.

Comment: @Yunnosch by doesn't work i mean i get the wrong result am sorry that my code is inefficient am still learning

Comment: I understand this question. It's actually one issue here rather than a stack of them. OP has no idea how to find the index of a byte array within a file without reading the whole file into memory. It's a fairly straightforward algorithm that I just don't feel like typing in right now. Maybe later.

Comment: `i+size <=size+1` (in the `for` in main) is mostly the same as `i <= 1`. This means it'll only check once (with `i = 0`) and the loop won't actually loop.